# How to reference a cell in a powerbi / dax table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a table with parameter values to use in formulas in PowerBi.

What I want to do is to be able to refer to those parameters

so if I want to do if (columnA > para1, 1, 0)

[image]

however I don't find a way to create a reference to individual cells

So how can is reference the value in row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knZYj.png)column[Boundary] of the attached table?

Answer (score 1):

With Power Query Parameter
In power query window, you need to `Enable Load` of the parameter and the load the parameter. By default the load is nor enabled.

Then you can do following

```
Column = IF([Column2]>MAX(para1[para1]),1,0)
```

[image: Solution]

With DAX Parameter

```
Column 2 = IF([Column2]>Parameter[Parameter Value],1,0)
```

[image: Solution]

DAX Parameter Table with the calculated column and measure respectively

```
Parameter = GENERATESERIES(20, 20, 1)
Parameter Value = SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter])
```